Typesetting a long wide table in LaTeX
I'm stuck trying to properly render a quite big table.
Right now I've focused on the "wide" problem. In this regard I've tried to:

Reduce the \tabcolsep
Change orientation to landscape with pdflandscape
Reduce the font size to \tiny
Use tabularx package to adapt the column width of the widest columns. This results in  text from these columns overlapping horizontally.

What am I doing wrong? Why is tabularx overlapping columns?
Once I sort out the "wide" problem I guess I'll have to split the table along a few pages. If I'm no wrong I can use longtable for that but I don't know how to combine it with tabularx.
If this proves to be too challenging I thought of either directly skip this table and put a QR code or creating it in Word and appending the pdf generated (which I would hate tbh).
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
            \tiny
            \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{ccccXXXXXXXXXXXccccc}
                \textbf{algorithm} & \textbf{.config} & \textbf{.iter} & \textbf{preproc} & \textbf{model} & \textbf{.estimator} & \textbf{accuracy} & \textbf{balanced accuracy} & \textbf{detection prevalence} & \textbf{F1 measure} & \textbf{j index} & \textbf{kappa index} & \textbf{matthews correlation coefficient} & \textbf{negative predictive value} & \textbf{positive predictive value} & \textbf{precision} & \textbf{recall} & \textbf{roc\_auc} & \textbf{sensitivity} & \textbf{specificity} \\
                SLNN                                   & Preprocessor1\_Model02               & 0                                  & recipe                               & mlp                                & binary                                  & 0,895333                              & 0,891666667                                      & 0,425333333                                         & 0,867428571                             & 0,7833                               & 0,786200466                              & 0,80939558                                                      & 0,902333333                                              & 0,938333333                                              & 0,9383333                              & 0,847                               & 0,957222                              & 0,84666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                SLNN                                   & Iter9                                & 9                                  & recipe                               & mlp                                & binary                                  & 0,886333                              & 0,885                                            & 0,442333333                                         & 0,863428571                             & 0,77                                 & 0,771005661                              & 0,796860103                                                     & 0,907333333                                              & 0,921666667                                              & 0,9216667                              & 0,857                               & 0,943333                              & 0,85666667                               & 0,91333333                               \\
                SLNN                                   & Preprocessor1\_Model07               & 0                                  & recipe                               & mlp                                & binary                                  & 0,872333                              & 0,875                                            & 0,479                                               & 0,859428571                             & 0,75                                 & 0,745927406                              & 0,77467991                                                      & 0,922                                                    & 0,881666667                                              & 0,8816667                              & 0,883                               & 0,897778                              & 0,88333333                               & 0,86666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model01               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model02               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model03               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model04               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model05               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model07               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model08               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model09               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model12               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model13               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model15               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model16               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model17               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model18               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model19               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,945                                 & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model20               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,876333                              & 0,871666667                                      & 0,406333333                                         & 0,849757046                             & 0,7433                               & 0,745944056                              & 0,786676108                                                     & 0,882333333                                              & 0,930272109                                              & 0,9302721                              & 0,807                               & 0,943333                              & 0,80666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                SLNN                                   & Preprocessor1\_Model11               & 0                                  & recipe                               & mlp                                & binary                                  & 0,868                                 & 0,87                                             & 0,470666667                                         & 0,848809524                             & 0,74                                 & 0,735994006                              & 0,762916847                                                     & 0,910666667                                              & 0,880333333                                              & 0,8803333                              & 0,867                               & 0,889444                              & 0,86666667                               & 0,87333333                               \\
                Logistic Reg.                          & Preprocessor1\_Model14               & 0                                  & recipe                               & logistic\_reg                      & binary                                  & 0,881333                              & 0,876666667                                      & 0,411333333                                         & 0,846095238                             & 0,7533                               & 0,755944056                              & 0,782489591                                                     & 0,885666667                                              & 0,931666667                                              & 0,9316667                              & 0,817                               & 0,946667                              & 0,81666667                               & 0,93666667                               \\
                SLNN                                   & Preprocessor1\_Model17               & 0                                  & recipe                               & mlp                                & binary                                  & 0,867333                              & 0,865                                            & 0,453333333                                         & 0,845761905                             & 0,73                                 & 0,731914752                              & 0,760654557                                                     & 0,900333333                                              & 0,897                                                    & 0,897                                  & 0,847                               & 0,891111                              & 0,84666667                               & 0,88333333                               \\       
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}

Please note that I had to shorten the original table since StackExchange doesn't let me include such a big quantity of characters.
Thanks for your time in advance!

Please complete your example (\begin/end{document} is missing)

Plus you are not loading tabularx so your doc cannot compile.

Sorry for that @daleif, it should be fine now :)

Please try with rotating.sty instead of pdflscape and the environment is begin{sidewaystable}....\end{sidewaystable} instead of \begin{landscape}         \begin{table}...

@MadyYuvi I tried, but I don't see why that was presented as a solution. First, it doesn't rotate the page, only the table, and second the table still has the same problem of the columns overlapping. I understand the problem is with tabularx declaration that I'm doing wrong.

You have a lot of text that you're trying to squeeze in.  Even without worrying about a table, the fourth line
Logistic Reg. Preprocessor1\_Model01 0 recipe logistic\_reg binary 0,876333 0,871666667 0,406333333 0,849757046 0,7433 0,745944056 0,786676108 0,882333333 0,930272109 0,9302721 0,807 0,943333 0,80666667 0,93666667

takes over a line of the page.  So we're going to have to get drastically creative.
The first thing is to use siunitx and wrapp all of those numbers with \num{} so that we can control how they are formatted.  Rounding them to 3 places after the decimal will save a lot of space.
Since you're not needing line breaks within your text, just your headings, lets get rid of the X columns and use S columns to align on the decimal separator.  This means we can remove tabularx for tabular (otherwise, we would also want to change \textheight to \linewidth).
The next thing to save space is to remove redundancy.  Your preproc is always binary, so we'll more that to the table's caption.  Similarly, model is always recipe.  I'm also going to abbreviate linear regression in the algorithm and .estimator columns, and Preprocessor1_Model in the .config column.  All of this should be explained in your text, and then summarized in your table caption.
To further save space, we can wildly abbreviate all of the headings, and explain what we're doing in the text with the table (if you weren't explaining already, the table would be meaningless).
Now that we're manually linebreaking the headings, we should combine the accuracy columns and the predictive value columns.  We should also allow the default column separation, since the numbers run together too much otherwise.  We should also use the rules from booktabs, and don't need to bold the table headers.  And I took out all the extra spacing in the tex source, since I didn't see a reason to have it.
Your physical page setup is a bit odd.  You specify the top and bottom margins, but not the left and right.  Also, b5 paper is smaller than the usual a4 or letter, so make sure that's what you want.
We end up with
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}
 
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[round-precision=3,round-mode=places,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}
  \tiny
  \caption{binary preproc, recipe model, LR=Logistic Regression, P1M=Preprocessor1\_Model}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccSSSSSSSSSSSccccc}\toprule
  algo & .config & {.iter} & {.est} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{accuracy} & {detect} & {F1} & $j$ & $\kappa$ & {matthews} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{predictive value} & {prec} & {recall} & roc\_auc & {sens} & {spec} \\
  &&&& {reg} & {bal} & {prev} &&&& {corr coeff} & {neg} & {pos} \\
  \midrule
  SLNN & P1M02 & 0 & mlp & \num{0,895333} & \num{0,891666667} & \num{0,425333333} & \num{0,867428571} & \num{0,7833} & \num{0,786200466} & \num{0,80939558} & \num{0,902333333} & \num{0,938333333} & \num{0,9383333} & \num{0,847} & \num{0,957222} & \num{0,84666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  SLNN & Iter9 & 9 & mlp & \num{0,886333} & \num{0,885} & \num{0,442333333} & \num{0,863428571} & \num{0,77} & \num{0,771005661} & \num{0,796860103} & \num{0,907333333} & \num{0,921666667} & \num{0,9216667} & \num{0,857} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,85666667} & \num{0,91333333} \\
  SLNN & P1M07 & 0 & mlp & \num{0,872333} & \num{0,875} & \num{0,479} & \num{0,859428571} & \num{0,75} & \num{0,745927406} & \num{0,77467991} & \num{0,922} & \num{0,881666667} & \num{0,8816667} & \num{0,883} & \num{0,897778} & \num{0,88333333} & \num{0,86666667} \\
  LR & P1M01 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M02 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M03 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M04 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M05 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M07 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M08 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M09 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M12 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M13 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M15 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M16 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M17 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M18 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M19 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,945} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  LR & P1M20 & 0 & LR & \num{0,876333} & \num{0,871666667} & \num{0,406333333} & \num{0,849757046} & \num{0,7433} & \num{0,745944056} & \num{0,786676108} & \num{0,882333333} & \num{0,930272109} & \num{0,9302721} & \num{0,807} & \num{0,943333} & \num{0,80666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  SLNN & P1M11 & 0 & mlp & \num{0,868} & \num{0,87} & \num{0,470666667} & \num{0,848809524} & \num{0,74} & \num{0,735994006} & \num{0,762916847} & \num{0,910666667} & \num{0,880333333} & \num{0,8803333} & \num{0,867} & \num{0,889444} & \num{0,86666667} & \num{0,87333333} \\
  LR & P1M14 & 0 & LR & \num{0,881333} & \num{0,876666667} & \num{0,411333333} & \num{0,846095238} & \num{0,7533} & \num{0,755944056} & \num{0,782489591} & \num{0,885666667} & \num{0,931666667} & \num{0,9316667} & \num{0,817} & \num{0,946667} & \num{0,81666667} & \num{0,93666667} \\
  SLNN & P1M17 & 0 & mlp & \num{0,867333} & \num{0,865} & \num{0,453333333} & \num{0,845761905} & \num{0,73} & \num{0,731914752} & \num{0,760654557} & \num{0,900333333} & \num{0,897} & \num{0,897} & \num{0,847} & \num{0,891111} & \num{0,84666667} & \num{0,88333333} \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{landscape}
\end{document}



Wow! Thanks a lot for your effort! That's a lot of work. I have to re-check the table. As I mentioned in the OP, I shortened it, but I think unfortunately, that we cannot skip those two columns because they change. I managed to get this table inside a Word A4 document, but of course this book needs to be B5 and I forgot about that fact. Anyway, the table is waaay longer. How can I make it multi-page according to your new setup? Thanks a lot again, really :)

@jpm92 You had included b5paper in your original MWE.  I was hoping it was a mistake, but no.  It shouldn't be too hard to go from a regular tabular to a longtable.  Once you reintroduce the columns, if you need the space you can continue with abbreviating column headers and possibly switching to 2 decimal places instead of 3.  If you really need to squeeze a bit more out, you can rotate the longer column headers, but I think abbreviating is better.

may I ask you how did you do the transformation for the numbers and substitutions? Did you use regex and scripting (maybe R or Python?). I have several tables like this one that I have to format.
Also I'll fight with longtables and let's see what I achieve. Thanks again

TBH, it was just find and replace.  For the \num, it was changing & to } & \num{ and then fixing the first and last of each row (after having removed all the extra space characters).

Since you're providing the S column type for the relevant columns, it's not necessary to provide \num wrappers for the cell contents.

You can split the table across pages. This can be done with package hvfloat. In the middle of the double pages you have to insert some space (here 2cm):
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,includeheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[round-precision=3,round-mode=places,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}    
\Blindtext[10]

\hvFloat[capPos=bottom,doublePage]{table}{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{*4c 
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        @{\hspace{2cm}}
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        S[table-format = 3.3]
        *4c}\toprule
    algo & .config & {.iter} & {.est} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{accuracy} & {detect} & {F1} & $j$ & $\kappa$ & {matthews} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{predictive value} & {prec} & {recall} & roc\_auc & {sens} & {spec} \\
    &&&& {reg} & {bal} & {prev} &&&& {corr coeff} & {neg} & {pos} \\
    \midrule
    SLNN & P1M02 & 0 & mlp & 0,895333 & 0,891666667
    & 0,425333333 & 0,867428571 & 0,7833 & 0,786200466 & 0,80939558 & 0,902333333 & 0,938333333 & 0,9383333 & 0,847 & 0,957222 & 0,84666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    SLNN & Iter9 & 9 & mlp & 0,886333 & 0,885 & 0,442333333 & 0,863428571 & 0,77 & 0,771005661 & 0,796860103 & 0,907333333 & 0,921666667 & 0,9216667 & 0,857 & 0,943333 & 0,85666667 & 0,91333333 \\
    SLNN & P1M07 & 0 & mlp & 0,872333 & 0,875 & 0,479 & 0,859428571 & 0,75 & 0,745927406 & 0,77467991 & 0,922 & 0,881666667 & 0,8816667 & 0,883 & 0,897778 & 0,88333333 & 0,86666667 \\
    LR & P1M01 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M02 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M03 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M04 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M05 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M07 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M08 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M09 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M12 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M13 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M15 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M16 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M17 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M18 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M19 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,945 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    LR & P1M20 & 0 & LR & 0,876333 & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046 & 0,7433 & 0,745944056 & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109 & 0,9302721 & 0,807 & 0,943333 & 0,80666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    SLNN & P1M11 & 0 & mlp & 0,868 & 0,87 & 0,470666667 & 0,848809524 & 0,74 & 0,735994006 & 0,762916847 & 0,910666667 & 0,880333333 & 0,8803333 & 0,867 & 0,889444 & 0,86666667 & 0,87333333 \\
    LR & P1M14 & 0 & LR & 0,881333 & 0,876666667 & 0,411333333 & 0,846095238 & 0,7533 & 0,755944056 & 0,782489591 & 0,885666667 & 0,931666667 & 0,9316667 & 0,817 & 0,946667 & 0,81666667 & 0,93666667 \\
    SLNN & P1M17 & 0 & mlp & 0,867333 & 0,865 & 0,453333333 & 0,845761905 & 0,73 & 0,731914752 & 0,760654557 & 0,900333333 & 0,897 & 0,897 & 0,847 & 0,891111 & 0,84666667 & 0,88333333 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
  {binary preproc, recipe model, LR=Logistic Regression, P1M=Preprocessor1\_Model}
  {}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}

The image shows pages 4 (left) and 5 (right) of a double sided document.



With use of {tabular*}{\linewidth} and left column distance settings to macro \extracolsep{\fill}. Additionally is exploited S column types for formatting numbers in columns. Using it the font size in table can be enlarged to \footnotesize}:

\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\footnotesize
\caption{Binary preproc, recipe model, LR=Logistic Regression, P1M=Preprocessor1\_Model}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccc *{14}{S[round-precision=3,round-mode=places]}}
    \toprule
algo    & .config   & .iter & .est & \multicolumn{2}{c}{accuracy}
        & {detect}  & {F1}  & $j$  & $\kappa$ & {matthews} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{predictive value}
        & {prec}    & {recall} & roc\_auc & {sens} & {spec} \\
          
    \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    \cmidrule(l){12-13}
        &&&& {reg} & {bal} & {prev} &&&& {corr coeff} & {neg} & {pos} \\
  \midrule
SLNN    & P1M02 & 0 & mlp   & 0,895333      & 0,891666667 & 0,425333333 & 0,867428571   & 0,7833
                            & 0,786200466   & 0,80939558  & 0,902333333 & 0,938333333   & 0,9383333
                            & 0,847         & 0,957222    & 0,84666667  & 0,93666667    \\
SLNN    & Iter9 & 9 & mlp   & 0,886333      & 0,885       & 0,442333333 & 0,863428571   & 0,77
                            & 0,771005661   & 0,796860103 & 0,907333333 & 0,921666667   & 0,9216667
                            & 0,857         & 0,943333    & 0,85666667  & 0,91333333    \\
SLNN    & P1M07 & 0 & mlp   & 0,872333      & 0,875       & 0,479       & 0,859428571   & 0,75
                            & 0,745927406   & 0,77467991  & 0,922       & 0,881666667   & 0,8816667
                            & 0,883         & 0,897778    & 0,88333333  & 0,86666667    \\
LR      & P1M01 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M02 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M03 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M04 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M05 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M07 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433 
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M08 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M09 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M12 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M13 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M15 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M16 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M17 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M18 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M19 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,945       & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M20 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
SLNN    & P1M11 & 0 & mlp   & 0,868         & 0,87        & 0,470666667 & 0,848809524   & 0,74
                            & 0,735994006   & 0,762916847 & 0,910666667 & 0,880333333   & 0,8803333
                            & 0,867         & 0,889444    & 0,86666667  & 0,87333333    \\
LR      & P1M14 & 0 & LR    & 0,881333      & 0,876666667 & 0,411333333 & 0,846095238   & 0,7533
                            & 0,755944056   & 0,782489591 & 0,885666667 & 0,931666667   & 0,9316667
                            & 0,817         & 0,946667    & 0,81666667  & 0,9366666     \\
SLNN    & P1M17 & 0 & mlp   & 0,867333      & 0,865       & 0,453333333 & 0,845761905   & 0,73
                            & 0,731914752   & 0,760654557 & 0,900333333 & 0,897         & 0,897
                            & 0,847         & 0,891111    & 0,84666667  & 0,8833333     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}



By use talltblr of tabularray package. This package also define X column type an enable nicer table formatting (but this is paying with longer compilation time.

\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\footnotesize

\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Binary preproc, recipe model, LR=Logistic Regression, P1M=Preprocessor1\_Model},
note{a} = {MCC: matthews correct coefficient ?}
                ]{colsep  = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} lccc *{14}{X[c, si={round-precision=3,
                                                    round-mode=places,
                                                    table-format=1.3}]} @{}},
                 cell{1}{1-4,7-11,14-18} = {r=2}{},
                 column{5-Z}  = {colsep=0.25pt},
                 row{1,2}  = {guard, c, m},
                 row{3-Z}    = {rowsep=0.5pt},
                 row{odd[5]} = {abovesep=1ex}, 
                 }
    \toprule
algo    & .config   & .iter     & .est      & \SetCell[c=2]{}  accuracy
        &           & detect    &  F1       & $j$
        & $\kappa$  & MCC\TblrNote{a}
                                & \SetCell[c=2]{}  predictive value
        &           & prec      & recall    & roc\_auc
        & sens      & spec      \\
    \cmidrule[l]{5-6}
    \cmidrule[l]{12-13}
        &&&&  reg  &  bal       & prev      &&&&    & neg & pos     \\
  \midrule
SLNN    & P1M02 & 0 & mlp   & 0,895333      & 0,891666667 & 0,425333333 & 0,867428571   & 0,7833
                            & 0,786200466   & 0,80939558  & 0,902333333 & 0,938333333   & 0,9383333
                            & 0,847         & 0,957222    & 0,84666667  & 0,93666667    \\
SLNN    & Iter9 & 9 & mlp   & 0,886333      & 0,885       & 0,442333333 & 0,863428571   & 0,77
                            & 0,771005661   & 0,796860103 & 0,907333333 & 0,921666667   & 0,9216667
                            & 0,857         & 0,943333    & 0,85666667  & 0,91333333    \\
SLNN    & P1M07 & 0 & mlp   & 0,872333      & 0,875       & 0,479       & 0,859428571   & 0,75
                            & 0,745927406   & 0,77467991  & 0,922       & 0,881666667   & 0,8816667
                            & 0,883         & 0,897778    & 0,88333333  & 0,86666667    \\
LR      & P1M01 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M02 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M03 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M04 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M05 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M07 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M08 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M09 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M12 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M13 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M15 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M16 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M17 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M18 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M19 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,945       & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
LR      & P1M20 & 0 & LR    & 0,876333      & 0,871666667 & 0,406333333 & 0,849757046   & 0,7433
                            & 0,745944056   & 0,786676108 & 0,882333333 & 0,930272109   & 0,9302721
                            & 0,807         & 0,943333    & 0,80666667  & 0,93666667    \\
SLNN    & P1M11 & 0 & mlp   & 0,868         & 0,87        & 0,470666667 & 0,848809524   & 0,74
                            & 0,735994006   & 0,762916847 & 0,910666667 & 0,880333333   & 0,8803333
                            & 0,867         & 0,889444    & 0,86666667  & 0,87333333    \\
LR      & P1M14 & 0 & LR    & 0,881333      & 0,876666667 & 0,411333333 & 0,846095238   & 0,7533
                            & 0,755944056   & 0,782489591 & 0,885666667 & 0,931666667   & 0,9316667
                            & 0,817         & 0,946667    & 0,81666667  & 0,9366666     \\
SLNN    & P1M17 & 0 & mlp   & 0,867333      & 0,865       & 0,453333333 & 0,845761905   & 0,73
                            & 0,731914752   & 0,760654557 & 0,900333333 & 0,897         & 0,897
                            & 0,847         & 0,891111    & 0,84666667  & 0,8833333     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}



+1 for suggesting the use of a tabular* environment and for making good use of the capabilities of the S column type. :-)

@Mico, thank you very much!
